# Session not save in bea weblogic 10.3

Tags: session, weblogic-10.x

How to config my web application to work with sessions in bea weblogic?
In the web.xml there are this lines:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

In the weblogic.xml:

```
<session-descriptor>
    <persistent-store-type>memory</persistent-store-type>
    <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

My question is how to config the server to work with session and when I do this:

```
 _sess.setAttribute("user",user);
 ...............................
 User user = (User ) _sess.getAttribute("user");
```

The variable `user` not to be null?

Comment: Print out your session id at a few points in the code to see if it remains consistent. Also see if either of these links helps: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2303113 http://objectmix.com/weblogic/541694-urgent-problem-sharing-httpsession-object-between-jsp-andservlets.html

Comment: I do not have problem with my code. It's working properly on OAS 10.1.2 but on Bea Weblogic it's not.